# Sharepoint views: default vs allitems

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

So I was working on a list and noticed a difference in the way the views load. The default view on the list is titled "allitems" and is set up perfect as of now. When I put the list on the team site page, it is added in with a different view than the default I just created (see pics below). How can I add in the list on a page so that the list displays the correct view? 
[image: List selected view]

[image: List view from team site]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On the Team site page, edit the page and edit the list web part
2. choose the view you would like to add. (Screen Shot 1)

If you don't find a view that works for you, create another view (starting from the all items view) and it should show on the drop down to choose from! (Screen Shot 2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess where I got confused was in the ribbon, where it says my current view: default, if I clicked on allitems in the ribbon it took me to the list and didn't change the view

Comment: you can always modify that view as well. Under the drop down, you will see Edit the Current View where you can choose all the columns you would like to see!

Comment: That's what I had been doing, but not that I know the view is hidden in web part properties I will save so much time. Thanks Again!

Comment: you are most welcome!